# Scarlet websocket in Android application with coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I'm trying to implement application, which will work with websocket. So I choose scarlet. I can see in logs a response from a server, but I cant consume a data in my viewModel. How to do that? I am using Koin + viewModel + coroutine

Module for Koin

```
val networkModule = module {
    single { createScarlet() }
    single <ChatSocketRepository> {
        ChatSocketRepositoryImpl(get())
    }
}

private fun createScarlet(): ChatSocketApi {
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(DataProviderImplementation.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(DataProviderImplementation.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(DataProviderImplementation.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        })
        .build()

    return Scarlet.Builder()
        .webSocketFactory(client.newWebSocketFactory("wss://demos.kaazing.com/echo"))
        .addMessageAdapterFactory(GsonMessageAdapter.Factory())
        .addStreamAdapterFactory(CoroutinesStreamAdapterFactory())
        .build()
        .create()
}
```

ChatSocketApi

```
interface ChatSocketApi {
    @Receive
    fun observeText(): ReceiveChannel<String>
}
```

ChatSocketRepository

```
interface ChatSocketRepository {
    fun observeTest(): ReceiveChannel<String>
}
```

ChatSocketRepositoryImpl:

```
class ChatSocketRepositoryImpl(private val api: ChatSocketApi) : ChatSocketRepository {
    override fun observeTest(): ReceiveChannel<String> {
        return api.observeText()
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel(private val chatSocketRepository: ChatSocketRepository) : BaseViewModel() {
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val text = chatSocketRepository.observeTest().consumeEach {
                Log.d("SOCKET", it.toString())
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/Tinder/Scarlet/issues/114 

Found an example here

Comment: im going to implement this code but i think have a problem from web socket server "wss://demos.kaazing.com/echo"

can you give me a right url for test this code?

Comment: @RezaZavareh thank you for the interest, but this ticket is 2 years old, so this task is not actual

Answer (score 0):

you already get the data, and your data is String because you declare `ReceiveChannel<String>` you can use the received data and put it in a LiveData. change the value of livedata in the `.consumeEach{}`  method instead.